# Can't get onTouchListener to work in fragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to toast when a particular editText is hit in my fragment.

My fragment activity:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        EditText ed2 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ed2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()){

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

My application crashes when this fragment is added. I'm getting a null pointer at `ed2.setOnTouchListener...`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EditText is null.
if your contentview is not cotain edittext , edittext can't created.
OnTouchListener is not null.
first check EditText .

Answer (score 1):

use onCreateView

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_view, container, false);
    EditText = ed2 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```